# combine multiple lines into one column

Tags: python, pandas, merge, sum

Here is my dataframe following the merging of two separate dataframes.

In the `[order]` column, orders 2, 4 and 5, have multiple corresponding amounts in the `[value]` column. This is replicated elsewhere in the dataframe at random points. What can I do to merge these amounts so that I am left with one row in the dataframe per order:

Essentially, how do I sum the values against each order line leaving me with one amount in the `[value]` columns for each row of the dataframe?

[image]

So my desired output will look something like:

```
order customer value  ordered     delivered
1     832      3450.0 2015-01-01  2015-01-02
2     803      607.0  2015-01-01  2015-01-02
3     105      135.0  2015-01-01  2015-01-02
4     57       667.8  2015-01-01  2015-01-02
5     905      1056.0 2015-01-01  2015-01-02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if `order` is column use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['value'] = df.groupby(df['order'].replace('', np.nan).ffill())['value'].transform('sum')

df = df.drop_duplicates('order')
```

If `order` is level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df['value'] = df.groupby(level=0)['value'].transform('sum')

df = df[~df.index.get_level_values('order').duplicated()]
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for these suggestions. the first two result in duplicate rows: so the values are summed but I am left with duplicates of row order 2, 4 and 5...

Comment: @EdJefferies - Sure, if need new column then it is expected.

Comment: @EdJefferies - Or need repalce duplicated values by missing values `NaN`?

Comment: have added my desired output above, apologies for not being clearer

Comment: @EdJefferies - `order` is column or level?

Comment: column I believe.

Comment: @EdJefferies - If level working only second solution. How working 1. or 2. solution in your real data?